# C++ std::thread should be created on heap or on stack

Tags: c++, multithreading, heap-memory, stack-memory, detach

Lets say i have a thread that is being created and detached on the stack like this:

```
void foo()
{
    while(true){};
}

void runThread()
{
    std::thread t(foo);
    t.detach();
}

int main()
{
    runThread();
}
```

The program means nothing of course, But what happens after we detach and exit `runThred` ? it was allocated on the stack so basically `t` will be destroyed after we exit `runThred`, but the thread itself will go on running regardless to the main thread because it is detached.

Is the best practice in such an example is to create it on the heap and save a pointer to it doing whatever (dcor) after that?

Or it means nothing if the `t` variable is destructed and we should just "ignore" it?

Comment: Why would you keep a pointer to it?  Once you call `detach` you no longer  own the thread.

Comment: so what happens to 't'? it's being killed ofc, but it means nothing?

Comment: You should read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).  It explains hows this works.

Comment: once you detach `t`, it's a zombie. destroying it is a NOP.

Comment: You should be very clear to distinguish when you're talking about the `std::thread` object and when you're talking about the thread itself (the thing that's scheduled and runs code).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for your comment, so this basically means 't' is not relevant for the thread's execution, it should be used just for the detach part. did i understand correctly?

Comment: @Itzik984 Once you call `detach` there is no connection between the `std::thread` object and the thread.

Comment: Thanks @DavidSchwartz. mind posting an answer with a short explanation so that i will be able to accept it?

Comment: `std::thread t(foo())` should be `std::thread t(foo)`

Comment: @immibis thanks, will fix

Comment: One thing worth adding is that once you've detached from the thread, there is nothing to prevent `main` from returning and the program from exiting, possibly unceremoniously killing the thread before the thread has finished executing.

Comment: Avoid detaching threads. Don't create `std::thread` objects on the heap, if you need to pass them to another scope, `std::move` them. Tip: Store your `std::thread` objects in a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `std::thread` object represents a handle to the thread through which it can be operated on. But once you call `detach` there is no connection between the object and the actual thread of execution.